# Mui returning Date with Time, flask api returning "incorrect date value"

Tags: reactjs, flask, material-ui, datepicker, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi im using Mui's date picker on my front end

```
         <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <TimePicker
                name='timeValue'
                label="Time"
                type="time"
                value={this.state.timeValue}
                onChange={e => this.onTimeChange(e)}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
            />
```

it allows me to chose my date fine but when i console log it or send it to my flask backend i see that its also attached with a time that i would not like as my flask backend uses the MYSQL "DATE" type and the endpoint that recives the data is expeceting it to meet the following requirment

DB class: `Date = db.Column(db.DATE)`

Flask endpoint:
`'Date': self.Date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),`

the error i get from my flask back end is `Incorrect date value: '2022-06-09T06:47:12.000Z' for column 'Date' at row 1"`

any tips on what i need to change on my backend or front end? i was able to change the input format to 'yyyy/MM/dd' on the Mui datpicker but i dont have a clue as to how i can get it to drop the date that comes along with it or how my backend can take care of it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to choose date, so i think you should use `DatePicker` and use `moment` to format your date value

```
import moment from "moment";

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
        name='timeValue'
        label="Time"
        type="time"
        value={this.state.timeValue}
        onChange={e => this.onTimeChange(moment(e).format("yyyy/MM/DD"))}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
    />
```